# How To Run Apache Hudi Hive Sync Tool

Tags: apache-hudi

This documentation https://hudi.apache.org/docs/syncing_metastore is not really straightforward.

I've spent a lot of time trying to make this tool working.
Whether I run it from CLI (run-sync-tools.sh) or from Intellij (Running HiveSyncTool directly) - I always receive ClassNotFoundException for different classes..

First exception is ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.. Ok I added dependency explicitly. But in continues..

In Intellij it's happening because almost all dependencies are with `provided` scope. I had to change to compile..

After resolving those exceptions I receive:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.parquet.schema.LogicalTypeAnnotation org.apache.parquet.schema.Type.getLogicalTypeAnnotation()'
```

This looks like parquet and avro libraries incompatibility. Tried different versions but without success.

The main question here - is there any easy way to run this tool? I don't believe it should be required ato add missing dependencies/changing Maven scope..  This is really weird.

Thanks in advance

Comment: yeah the tooling in general looks like not well maintained. I might be wrong. Please post an issue in hudi side